# LOGO Turtle-like in C++, drawing curves

Tags: c++, geometry, turtle-graphics, cimg

I am creating a LOGO Turtle-like object in C++ using the CImg library. When attempting to draw a circle, defined as the commands `repeat 360[fd 1 rt1]` which loops 360 times, moving forward 1 pixel and turning right 1 degree each iteration. With my code though **I am getting a more octagonal shape rather than an actual circle**.

Code for moving forward:

```
void turtle::fd(int distance)
{
int endx, endy;

endx = posx-(int)round((distance*sin(heading * PI / 180)));
endy = posy-(int)round((distance*cos(heading * PI / 180)));

if(pen)
   window->draw_line(posx, posy, endx, endy, color1, 1);

posx=endx;
posy=endy;
}
```

In CImg, `draw_line()` will draw a line from position `posx` `posy` to `endx` `endy`, the rest is color and opacity.

And for turning right:

```
void turtle::rt(int degree)
{
   heading -= degree;
   if(heading < 0)
      heading = (360-abs(heading));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the.x value use cos and the y value use sin?

Comment: Hah yes good call, doesn't fix the issue but is the proper way for coordinate rotation. Thanks